# Sort sub value from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Good day guys,

Been looking all day long for solution to this problem.

My Array looks like this.

```
[status] => success
[city] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [street] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'las vegas'
                    )
             {
        [1] => Array
            (
                [street] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 'york'
                    )
             {
```

my problem is this, I need to 
sort this array based on [name] (sample contents are 'las vegas', 'york'

already done things like 
**usort** and **uasort** and to my surpise, they ain't work at all.

thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Sample code of usort

```
 foreach($myArr['city'] as $city) {
      foreach($city['street'] as $street) {
           function sort ($a, $b) {
                return strcmp ($a['name'], $b['name']);
           }
      }
 }

 usort($myArr, 'sort');
```

Comment: Show us your code with usort because it should work

Comment: Your array doesn't looks proper because there is opening `curly` brackets without closing `curly`brackets.

Comment: sorry bro, it's just a sample of my array, didn't mean it is the whole array itself.

Answer (score 1):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) should work in your case. Please check your code.
 May be you're not using [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) to sort the array by name.

Following code should work.

```
<?php
$cities=array(
   array(
     "street"=> array (
         "name"=> 'las vegas'
     )
   ),
   array(
     "street"=> array (
         "name"=> 'C'
     )
   ),
   array(
     "street"=> array (
         "name"=> 'york'
     )
   ),
   array(
     "street"=> array (
         "name"=> 'A'
     )
   ),
   array(
     "street"=> array (
         "name"=> 'B'
     )
   ),
);

function sortByName($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["street"]["name"], $b["street"]["name"]);
}

usort($cities, 'sortByName');

?>
```

https://eval.in/586734

Comment: thanks bud, but one of the problem is,
the array i just showed is not the whole thing,
It is just a part of the array which I really care about. :(

Comment: But if you follow the same procedure this should work.

Comment: hmm. if you can see, there's a "wildcard" in between ['city'] and ['street'] and that's the thing I need to overcome. :(

Comment: What is your input array ? and what is your expected output?